# WAMP Mysqli not working whereas Mysql works

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli, wamp

I upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10 recently, and installed WAMP. This is my first time working with WAMP.

I am getting following error message in one of my Codeigniter project I was working in windows 7 setup and I don't know what to make of it. The page keeps on loading and loading and then fails with the error message.

> **Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002):** A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
>   after a period of time, or established connection failed because
>   connected host has failed to respond.

This is my database config settings :

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'studentx',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

If I change `'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',` part of the config to `'dbdriver' => 'mysql',` then it works with the warning of deprecated mysql extension.

What's going on ?

Comment: What are you getting warning?

Comment: Which version of wamp you are using?

Comment: did you found this line in php.ini file `extension=php_mysqli.dll`

Comment: @mrdragon Message: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead

Comment: @SimhachalamGulla Version 2.5

Comment: @SimhachalamGulla Yes, `extension=php_mysqli.dll` is uncommented in the php.ini file

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that the **php.ini** file is loading the **mysqli** extension.

How to check 
Click on wamp icon (taskbar) the icon in the system tray ,
go to PHP -> PHP Extensions and make sure **php_mysqli** is checked.
If not then
go into the php.ini file and make sure that the line: extension=php_mysqli.dll is uncommented (eg, remove the ; if it exists). If that line does not exist, add it.

php.ini path 
C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache*.*.*\bin\php.in

Comment: Yes, `php_mysqli` and `php_mysql` both are checked and `extension=php_mysqli.dll` is uncommented in the php.ini file

Comment: Can you please check process of Mysql from windows service manager ?
also check PORT for mysql process.
And Check phpmyadmin .

Answer (score 0):

Above Answer is also useful .But it may cause same problem if you were 
 running WAMP with two PHP versions 1) 5.2.9 and 2) 5.2.13.
As per site requirement i needed to change PHP version to 5.2.9 from 5.2.13. after swapping PHP version, error was "mysqli extension is missing". after debugging long time i get to know it was due to wrong "extension_dir" path in php.ini file.

So i changed its value:

```
Old: "extension_dir" c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.2.13/ext/

New: "extension_dir" c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.2.9/ext/
```

Restarted All services in wamp server, then it's fixed.

Comment: The `extension_dir" c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/` is correct for my php version install.

Answer (score 0):

In `php.ini` file: find to `error_reporting` and rewite `E_DEPRECATED` to `E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED`.
Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, i fixed it by changing localhost to 127.0.0.1

before:
'hostname' => 'localhost',

after:
'hostname' => '127.0.0.1',